I want to break down a string REST response and only store some parts of it in a Salesforce Object
I'm receiving a Json response from a REST callout and populating a custom object with that information. One of the required fields is Secondary Locations, for this field I'm receiving a list of locations with the format City, State, Country; but the business only wants to save the non repeating countries.
For example, if we receive this as the Secondary Locations for a specific record:
Boca Raton,FL,US; Houston,TX,US; Boston,MA,US; Charlotte,NC,US; San Francisco,CA,US; Boston,MA,US; Rochester,NY,US; Charleston,SC,US; Los Angeles,CA,US; Atlanta,GA,US; Singapore,Singapore; West Palm Beach,FL,US
I need to only save US, Singapore in the salesforce field.
I'm a beginner on REST services and I have manage to create a functioning solution to get the correct info from the external service, but this string processing has gotten the best of me. Thanks

Once you've gotten as far as having the string, you can do something like this:
Set<String> countries = new Set<String>();
for(String location: locationList.split(';')) {
  countries.add(location.substring(location.lastIndexOf(',')+1));
}

This gives you a unique list of strings after the last comma.
If you want to store this result as a string, make sure you use String.join to avoid the string being truncated in some cases.
record.Countries__c = String.join(countries, ', ');

